# How to use regex "named matches" in Xcode's "Search and Replace"?

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, search, text

I'm used to regular expression syntax which allows for “named matches” from the search string to be used in the construction of the replacement term. For example…

```
@property (strong) NSWindow *window; ➜  @pr.*\*  
➜ @property (strong) NSWindow
```

or

```
@property (strong) NSWindow *window; ➜  @pr.*\*(.*) ➜    
$1 ➜ window;
```

Ya, know… the first set of `(…)` is `$1`, second `(…)` is `$2`, etc…

Xcode *does* match the search string… but how can I *filter* the query string / pass the result to... the "Replace" portion of Xcode's "Search and Replace" function?

✌

[image: Regex matches dont seem to work in xcode.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a backslash instead of a dollar sign. `\1` matches the first group, and so on.

Comment: This does work..  however, it doesn't "traverse" more than one line.  That, I suppose, is an issue for another question, though…  Cheers.

Comment: What do you mean by "traverse"?